# JSON Success URL

Tags: php, json

Tengo una aplicacion web en PHP donde genero ingreso a un item. A este item puedo asignarle movimientos. lo hago con un `FORM POST`. Aparte tengo un boton donde puedo eliminarte esa asignación.

Este Metodo lo hice con `JSON`.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $('.view_data').click(function() {
             var code = $(this).attr('id');
             var val = $('#valor').val();
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'JSON/deleteJSON.php',
                 data: {
                     'code': code,
                     'val': val
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                    location.reload();

                     }
             });
             // End AJAX function
         });
     });
 </script>
```

En mi PHP

```
<?php
include_once '../include/conexion.php';
$codmenu = $_POST['code'];
$id = $_POST['val'];


$sql = "DELETE FROM ACT_FKAgenda WHERE id_fkagenda =$codmenu";
  $resultt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($resultt) {

   header("Refresh:0; url=../add-horas.php?id=$id&Borrado");

} else {

  header("Refresh:0; url=../add-horas.php?id=$id&ERROR");
}
?>
```

Al eliminarlo me refresca en la misma pagina, ya que en el JSON SUCCESS tengo la funcion `location.reload();` pero mi duda es si yo puedo hacerlo algo asi en JSON

```
header("Refresh:0; url=../add-horas.php?id=$id&Borrado");
```

Donde refresque en la pagina del item que estoy asignado movimientos y aparte me agrege el `$Borrado` al URL para yo poder usar un $_GET y mostrar un mensaje.

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

Comment: Osea, quieres que hacer una peticion por POSt y retorne por GET ?

Comment: Omita el header y en el success del ajax recargas la pagina que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar el mensaje en lugar del window reload

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'JSON/deleteJSON.php',
     data: {
         'code': code,
         'val': val
     },
     success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '&borrado=1'

     }
});
```

Aunque no le veo mucho sentido hacer una llamada ajax si al final de  cuentas vas a terminar recargando la página, podrías hacerlo directamente con el POST y redirigir a la misma página con el parámetro, o mostrar el mensaje deseado con js desde el success del ajax.

Comment: Funciono muy bien gracias!.

Comment: Alguna duda cuando asigno en mi PHP tengo me agrega el campo $DONE en mi URL y si estoy en el mismo URL y elimino me queda asi el URL `add-horas.php?id=21&Done&Borrado=1`

Comment: no he entendido, podrías xplicarte mejor?

Comment: Cuando borro el URL me genera la siguiente `add-horas.php?id=21&Borrado` Funciona bien me muestra el mensaje, pero si Agrego y borro a la vez en el URL me queda asi `add-horas.php?id=21&Done&Borrado`

Comment: No hay la forma que solo agregue  `add-horas.php?id=21&Borrado`

Comment: puedes intentar remover el parametro de la url, puedes revisar aquí como se hace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941104/remove-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript , hay una función hecha, solo pasas la url y le quitas el get param que quieres antes de pasarla al href

Comment: gracias por la info!